# Перезагрузка подгружаемого скрипта по клику

Tags: javascript, dom, скрипт

Всем привет! Помогите пжл
Есть два скрипта - 1ый отвечает за логику сайта и изменение контента в слайдере(js1.js) , 2ой это подгружаемая библиотека для слайдера (lightslider.min.js).
2ой скрипт применяется, но так как контент в слайдере изменяется после изменений 2ой скрипт уже не выполняется. Что делать?

```
<script src="js1.js"></script>
<script src="lightgallery-all.min.js"></script>
<script src="lg-autoplay.min.js"></script>
<script src="lg-fullscreen.min.js"></script>
<script src="lg-thumbnail.min.js"></script>
<script id="sliderScript" src="lightslider.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var refSld
    var refGal
    $(document).ready(function (){
        refGal = $('#aniimated-thumbnials').lightGallery({
            showThumbByDefault:true,
            addClass:'showThumbByDefault'
        })
        refSld = $('#aniimated-thumbnials').lightSlider({
            gallery: true,
            item: 1,
            loop: true,
            slideMargin: 0,
            thumbItem: 9
        });
    })
    $(document).on('click','#product1',function(){
    refSld.destroy()
    refGal.destroy()
    refGal = $('#aniimated-thumbnials').lightGallery({
            showThumbByDefault:true,
            addClass:'showThumbByDefault'
        })
    refSld = $('#aniimated-thumbnials').lightSlider({
            gallery: true,
            item: 1,
            loop: true,
            slideMargin: 0,
            thumbItem: 9
        })
    })
</script>
```

Слайдер поменялся, работает, но теперь не обновляется галерея, работает со старым списком из 2 двух фотографий, а новые уже не открывает
Так тоже не работает

Часть кода, которая сменяет контент:

```
if (a == 'product1'){
        var slider = $('#aniimated-thumbnials');
        var sliderImgs = [];

        sliderImgs[0] = $('<img>', {'src':"slider/1/2.jpg"})
        sliderImgs[1] = $('<img>', {'src':"slider/1/1.jpg", 'class':'wide_img'})
        sliderImgs[2] = $('<img>', {'src':"slider/1/3.jpg", 'class':'wide_img'})
        sliderImgs[3] = $('<img>', {'src':"slider/1/4.jpg"})
        sliderImgs[4] = $('<img>', {'src':"slider/1/5.jpg"})
        sliderImgs[5] = $('<img>', {'src':"slider/1/6.jpg"})
        sliderImgs[6] = $('<img>', {'src':"slider/1/7.jpg"})
        console.log(sliderImgs);
        for (var i = 0; i<sliderImgs.length; i++) {
            var source = sliderImgs[i].attr('src')
            console.log(source)
            var newLi = $('<li></li>',{'data-src':`${source}`})
            newLi.appendTo(slider)
            sliderImgs[i].appendTo(newLi)
        }
    }
```

сам по себе js работает, в html создаются новые li и img в ul, но не подставляется в слайдер

Код разметки:

```
<div class="demo justify-content-center row">
            <ul id="aniimated-thumbnials">
                <li data-src="slider/1/2.jpg">
                    <img src="slider/1/2.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li data-src="slider/1/1.jpg">
                    <img class="wide_img" src="slider/1/1.jpg"/>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: код приводите текстом а не картинками

Comment: я думаю, что дело не в библиотеке слайдера, а в логике его использованию/применения

Comment: @Дмытрык Поясните пожалуйста

Comment: 1) Покажите часть кода, которая изменяет контент; 2) Какую ошибку выбрасывает? 3) Ну и чтобы два раза не бегать - можно и разметку показать

Comment: @Дмытрык со сладером проблему решил путем destroy(), но теперь проблема осталась с галереей, не обновляет почему-то

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: refGal.destroy is not a function - выдает такую ошибку, хотя метод destroy() использую абсолютно одинаково